# Даны две переменные со словарем и словарем с вложенным списком. Как написать функцию в python для ДЗ?

Tags: python, функции, циклы

Есть исходная структура с хранимыми данными:

```
documents = [
{'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Василий Гупкин'},
{'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Геннадий Покемонов'},
{'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Аристарх Павлов'}
]

directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': []
}
```

Задача:Пользователь по команде “as” может добавить новую полку
Примеры работы:

Введите команду:
as

Введите номер полки:
10

Результат:
Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2, 3, 10.

Введите команду:
as

Введите номер полки:
1

Результат:
Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2, 3.

Сейчас реализовал следующий код:

```
def add_shelf():
    number_1 = input("Введите номер новой полки: ")
    #number = input("Введите номер полки: ")
    directories[number] = []
    for k in directories.items():
        if number in k:
            return ('Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: ') + str(k)
        else: 
            return (number_1) + str(directories[number])
number = input("Введите номер полки: ")
add_shelf()
```

Возвращает такой результат:
"Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: ('1', [])"

Не могу понять следующее:

1. Почему при запросе номера полки (которая есть в словаре) мне выходит результат:
   Введите номер новой полки;
2. Почему при вводе вводе существующей полки, выдает не полный список полок?
3. Почему при вводе несуществующей полки, не добавляется новая и не выводится весь список полок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Потому что у вас код функции начинается с такой строки, она выводится в любом случае:

```
number_1 = input("Введите номер новой полки: ")
```

2. Потому что вы сами сбрасываете имеющуюся полку в пустой список, видимо там должен быть `number_1` и этот код вместе с кодом п.1 должен работать при определённом условии:

```
directories[number] = []
```

3. Из-за ошибки в п.1 и п.2, а также из-за того, что `return` сразу возвращает управление, на первой же итерации цикла, остальные иитерации цикла не выполняются. Вам надо придумать что-то другое, как-то собрать всю информацию, прежде чем возвращать результат.